# how to convert specific string into a specific integer?

Tags: r

let's say an entire column named x has string values such as
x <- c("doctors", "firemen", "nurses")
x is a fct

i would like to convert 
doctor into a numerical 1
firemen to 2
nurses to 3

so that every instance of doctor in a column is automatically converted into 1 using R

I'm trying to use
mutate (x = factor(x, level = c("doctor", "firemen", "nurses"), labels = c(1,2,3)))

but it kept saying unknown object
please help

Comment: as.numeric(columname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x is a factor then `as.numeric(x)` returns the integer that represents the values.  If the default order is not what you want, then you can change the order of the levels using the factor function:

```
x <- factor(x, levels=c('doctor', 'fireman', 'nurse))
val <- as.numeric(x)
```

If you want numeric values other than 1 through the number of levels, then you can use a named vector as a look-up table:

```
lkp <- c( doctor=100, fireman=200, nurse=521 )
val <- lkp[ x ]
```